# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API : no validation message for string if sending null to both int and string

Tags: c#, validation, webapi, .net-core-3.1

I have a Web API and the TestModel is the parameter of a `POST` method in a controller.

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I mark `Number`, `Name` and `Address` as `[Required]`, but when I post, all of them are null:

```
{
    "Number": null,
    "Name": null,
     "Address": null
}
```

I get only 1 message saying:

> One or more validation errors occurred
>
> "status": 400,
>
> The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32.
> Path: $.Number | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 18

I expect they are 3 error messages for `Number`, `Name` and `Address` but it's only 1.

When I post a valid number for `Number`, then it shows the error messages for `Name` and `Address`:

> One or more validation errors occurred
> "status": 400
>
> The Name field is required
> The Address field is required

Is there any solution to make it return 3 messages if I post null for all of them?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like, you get the error message `The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32` before the validation failed. You have a field of type int and you try to set null which is not valid for int. Set the field to `int?` and try again. How does your validation look like?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian yes when I change it to nullable int? then they are 3 messages. Thanks for your help. But is it possible to do so with int (not nullable)?